# Quebra de linha flex

Tags: css3, flexbox

Tenho uma lista de vídeos que exibo em minha tela dinamicamente com java script. É uma tag div com que tem a classe vídeos. Porém a lista não quebram de linha quando o tamanho ultrapassa o tamanho do navegador e dá barra de rolagem horizontal.

Como faço em css, acho que tenho que usar o display flex para quebrar a linha. Alguém sabe como se faz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.elemento{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; // Quebra a linha
    flex-direction: row; //Direção que você deseja
}
```

Caso necessite de mais informações sobre flex-box. https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos/